# Can't show video thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, embed

Here's my application.js file. I'm using the jquery-embedly API:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:500,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){
      $('#video_div').append(oembed.thumbnail_url));
  });
});
```

That code doesn't work: the video is not embedded, nor is any thumbnail added to the `div` element. However, this code does work normally:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:500,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){
     alert(oembed.title);
  });
});
```

Why can't I get the thumbnail to show? Just in case, here is the view:

```
<div id="video_div"><%= link_to 'video', @video.video_url, :class => 'oembed' %></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to append the `thumbnail_url`, you want to append an image tag with an `src` attribute of the `thumbnail_url`:

```
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:500,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed) {
  $("#video_div").append($("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url }));
});
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how to specify the width for the thumbnail?

Comment: and on a side note, how did you know to use that kind of syntax that was passed to the .append() method? Is there documentation for this?

Comment: You can pass additional elements to the attributes hash to specify any attributes you want: `$("<img>", { src: oembed.thumbnail_url, width: 200 })`

Comment: It's not a parameter to `append`, it's a parameter to `$()`, which is also `jQuery()`. See [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Comment: thanks Brandon, i really appreciate the aid. you've always been very helpful :)